# How to give score when standing on a specific block and remove it when not standing on it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have two commands:

```
execute as @a[team=Thief] at @s run execute unless block ~ ~-1 ~ target run scoreboard players set @s krycie 0

execute as @a[team=Thief] run execute as @s at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ target run scoreboard players set @s krycie 1
```

those commands make a loop for some reason.

I want it so when a player stands on a target, they gain one score in "krycie" and when they leave the target, they lose one score in "krycie". I'm not sure what's wrong with the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target as block or entity?
Here's for the first command: (repeating command block)

`/execute as @a[team=Thief] at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:target run scoreboard players set @s krycie 1`

2nd command:

`/execute as @a[team=Thief] at @s unless block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:target run scoreboard players set @s krycie 0`

**Minecraft 1.19+**

Comment: Sorry if I didn't specify, yes I meant the target block. I will check this soon and mark it as a right answer if it works!

Comment: It works!, all I needed to do was change the target_block to just target. Thank you!